# Unable to install R and R Studio in Ubuntu 16.04. Help me in fixing errors!

Tags: 14.04, r, rstudio

After running this command :-

```
sudo echo "deb http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
```

I am getting this at the terminal :-

```
deb http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/
```

Than after running :-

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E084DAB9
```

I am getting an error :-

```
Executing: /tmp/tmp.O1hYtll8qh/gpg.1.sh --keyserver
keyserver.ubuntu.com
--recv-keys
E084DAB9
gpg: requesting key E084DAB9 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: keyserver timed out
gpg: keyserver receive failed: keyserver error
```

I also tried to run the above command using gpg but i am getting the same error.
I also tried changing the port to 80 but nothing which i tried is working.

Help me out with the installation.